# Customize the default footer when printing a page

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to move the footer of my print a little bit up. The footer is that one that comes automatically with the browser. In using Chrome and it shows like this: [footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjUQD.png)

I've tried using this:

```
@page{
    footer{
       margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

and also only with

```
@page{ margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Is there somehow I can do it? Or only with my own footer?

I want to move what's underlined to the box: [footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfh6U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you could solve your issue by using print styles in combination with the @page size. I referenced the normal landscape print page size, and the next line is height minus 10. I would take off however much you need to make the header move up.

```css
footer {
  background: red;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    /* size: 297mm 210mm;  landscape */
    size 297mm 200mm;
  }
  footer {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>FOOTER</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I'm not defining the <footer> in my html, the footer I'm taking about is the one that the browser puts when I print, like this: https://prnt.sc/0zjZVJ7GSVSa